# NetBeans -- does not represent a Valid javafx Scene Builder Instalattion

Tags: netbeans, scenebuilder

NetBeans

It was working properly and now it stopped working.

After choice correct directory with install SceneBuilder, in my case it is installed /opt/scenebuilder

This affects NetBeans version 12.2, 12.1, 12.0, in all the same problem.
It was working properly.
How to solve this problem?

Thank's

[image]

Comment: I have been facing the same problem (Linux Mint). You can start Scenebuilder separately and it works both ways (Scenebuilder changes are reflected in the fxml etc.), but I cannot get it to create or update the controller (even after creating oine manually).

Comment: Found another option. Don't use the Package Manager to install Scenebuilder. It installs in /opt/scenebuilder. That gives the error when trying to browse to it in Netbeans. Instead download it from Gluon and extract it into a directory of your choice. Now browse to that directory (where the Scenebuilder 'executable' is installed) and select it under Netbeans/options/Java/JavaFX... browse for folder. That works for me.

Comment: But the deb that is downloaded from gluon automatically places it in /opt/scenebuilder.
How is it possible to change this installation directory? , My version is JavaFX 15.0.1

Comment: I just checked my version of Scenebuilder and remembered that I too could not get it work with the latest version. So I downloaded 8.5.0, installed it and that works fine.

Comment: PS Here is my system info running on Linux Mint 20.1: Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0
Java: 15.0.2; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 15.0.2+7-27
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 15.0.2+7-27
System: Linux version 5.4.0-65-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_NZ (nb)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Netbeans 12.4 on Ubuntu 20.04 and Scene Builder 16.0.0 installed via download of the Gluon Scene Builder .deb file.

After many wrong attempts of assuming that the Netbeans 12.4 UI was expecting a path to the actual executable... - I finally got Scene Builder 16.0.0 to work in NB 12.4 simply by setting the "Scene Builder Home:"  to: "/opt/scenebuilder" and now I have the "open" option on right-clicking on a .fxml file (and it opens the clicked fxml file in Scene Builder).